# Unable To change the title foreground of Jinternal Frame

Tags: java, custom-controls, titlebar, foreground, jinternalframe

I am able to change the font of Titlebar of JinternalFrame but i am unable to change the foreground of Jinternalframe ...I tried using following code but dint worked

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground", Color.red);
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.activeTitleForeground", Color.blue);  
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.inactiveTitleBackground", Color.black);
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.inactiveTitleForeground", Color.yellow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Those values are used by the Basic LAF.

However your LAF is probably extending the basic LAF to do painting using different values.

Check out [UIManager Default](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). This class displays the default for each component.

Check out the "System Colors" items. You "might" get lucky and find some values there that you can override.

However the actual logic to determine the colors would be found in a class like `MetalInternalFrameTitlePane` or `WindowsInternalFrameTitlePane`. So you would need to look at the actual source code to see what is happening. Frankly the logic is too confusing for me to follow, maybe you will have better luck.